# At what point is gradle distributionSha256Sum checked

Tags: security, gradle

I want to add distributionSha256Sum to my project - so I added

```
distributionSha256Sum=203f4537da8b8075e38c036a6d14cb71b1149de5bf0a8f6db32ac2833a1d1294
```

to gradle-wrapper.properties

but then I wanted to trigger an error and changed the hash. It did not produce any error when building. Even after deleting .gradle I could still build. So when exactly is this hash checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Checksum Verification is only performed if the configured Wrapper distribution hasn’t been downloaded yet.
> https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Therefore just changing the hash and then triggering a rebuild does not trigger a hash check.

You have to clear the gradle wrapper cache in your home directory (`~/.gradle/wrapper/dists`) or at least remove the used gradle version from that cache.

Comment: Thanks - is there any chance to get verification on other points also? Would like a verification of the file that is already downloaded to be sure it has the hash i expect and was not manipulated.